# Getting return without gosub in my own function in vba

Tags: vba, return

I've been battling with vba for a bit and surprisingly it's not getting much better.
I have written the following code so I can have a special comparison operator for an object.

```
Public Function myEquals(v As CCtypestore) As Boolean

    If v Is Nothing Then
        myEquals = False
        Return
    End If

    If Me.Acronym = v.Acronym Then
        myEquals = True
        Return
    End If

    myEquals = False
    Return
End Function
```

The object v I'm passing in is Nothing at the moment so I would have sort of expected the result to be a trivial False. Surprisingly instead I'm getting an error Return without gosub. Any clue why that might be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Delete the `Return` statements!

In VBA, you set the return value with the line `myEquals = ...`.

All in all, you can reduce your function to the following code:

```
Public Function myEquals(v As CCtypestore) As Boolean
    If Not v Is Nothing Then
        myEquals = (Me.Acronym = v.Acronym)
    End If
End Function
```

Alternatively, use this:

```
Public Function myEquals(v As CCtypestore) As Boolean
    On Error Goto ErrorHandler
    myEquals = (Me.Acronym = v.Acronym)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    myEquals = False
End Function
```

`Return` is an old relic if you want to work with direct jumps in the code, i.e. build spaghetti code! See this example from the help file:

```
Sub GosubDemo()
Dim Num
' Solicit a number from the user.
    Num = InputBox("Enter a positive number to be divided by 2.")
' Only use routine if user enters a positive number.
    If Num > 0 Then GoSub MyRoutine    
    Debug.Print Num
    Exit Sub    ' Use Exit to prevent an error.
MyRoutine:
    Num = Num/2    ' Perform the division.
    Return    ' Return control to statement.
End Sub    ' following the GoSub statement.
```

Comment: Ahh so I should be using exit instead of return then? Thank you

Comment: in your case you don't even need `Exit Function` as you have no errorhandler or similar. `End Function` is sufficient!

Comment: Early return vs highly nested code is arguable, see the web there's loads of arguments about it !

Comment: @HaveAGuess: i agree, in fact I'm a big fan of early return - much better than nested code. However, even then you'd use `Exit Function` and not `Return`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Exit Function` instead of `Return`.

You can also avoid those `Exit Function` by using a construction like

```
If .... Then  
    'some code
ElseIf...Then 
   'some other code
ElseIf...Then 
   'etc 
Else  
   'final 
End if
```