# Vba: ‘On error’ statement safety

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I made a macro that records, then changes the local settings (in my case the decimal separator). At the end of the macro it would restore the settings.

When there is an error I make the program also restore the local settings using the ‘on error’ statement.
(A simplified  example of the program is given below)

So far I got no issues; however, as I am now planning to transfer the program to my working colleagues, I really wish to not interfere with them and overwrite their own local settings.

Does the `On error` statement is here safe enough to use and make sure that the settings are restored?

Is there any case where the program could run into an error that the `On error` would fail to redirect to the error handler?

PS: I already know I can convert all my numbers using `String = Replace(Number, ",", ".")` but for some reasons I cannot afford to go through all the many variables of the macro.

Example Code:

```
Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID% Lib "kernel32" ()
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfoA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetLocaleInfoA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String) As Boolean

Sub test()
  ' what to do on error
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
  ' define a number (Your local settings are set up to
  Dim MyNumber As Single
  MyNumber = 0.03
  MsgBox ("Number is 0,03 ->" & MyNumber)
  ' record the settings in the variable LocalSettingsDecimal
  Dim LocalSettingsDecimal As String
  Dim Buffer As String
  Buffer = String(256, 0)
  Dim le As Integer
  le = GetLocaleInfoA(GetUserDefaultLCID(), 14, Buffer, Len(Buffer))
  LocalSettingsDecimal = Left(Buffer, le - 1)

  ' force decimal settings to '.'
  Call SetLocaleInfoA(GetUserDefaultLCID(), 14, ".")

  ' Now is the program body
  MsgBox ("Number is now 0.03 ->" & MyNumber)
  ' an unfortunate error:
  MyNumber = "aa"

  Call SetLocaleInfoA(GetUserDefaultLCID(), 14, LocalSettingsDecimal)
  MsgBox ("Number should be back 0,03 ->" & MyNumber)
  Exit Sub
  ErrorHandler:
  Call SetLocaleInfoA(GetUserDefaultLCID(), 14, LocalSettingsDecimal)
  MsgBox ("There was an error but it's ok, it should be back to 0,03 ->" & MyNumber)
End Sub
```

Comment: General rule: **never** change a user's desktop settings just to make your code work.

Comment: haha, thank you for the insight @Rory

Comment: The instruction separator / colon is superfluous at the end of the `On Error` statement. `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` is all you need. That said, @Rory's recommendation wasn't a joke - it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve, but tampering with the user's local settings is a sloppy work-around for sloppy code. Write code that isn't locale-dependent instead. Treat numbers as numbers, not strings, for a start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways VBA code can get interrupted, some not even involving a clever user that would break on a `MsgBox` and hit the <kbd>Stop</kbd> button: If the host crashes for of something completely unrelated to your code (some KB updates come to mind), in the middle of a procedure's execution, then your error handlers won't be jumped into and there's nothing you can do to prevent that.

Don't tamper with user's local settings. Fix your code instead.

> *I already know I can convert all my numbers using `String = Replace(Number, ",", ".")`*

Your code is treating numbers as strings, or vice-versa. If the number came from a cell in a worksheet, you can read it into a `Double` without having to think about what the user's decimal separator is.

```
Dim myNumber As Double
With ActiveSheet
    If IsNumeric(.Range("A1").Value) And Not IsError(.Range("A1").Value) Then myNumber = CDbl(.Range("A1").Value)
    'myNumber contains a valid numeric value
End With
```

If the number came from a textbox on a UserForm you crafted, and you allowed the user to enter a comma when your code requires that to be a dot, then you need to fix your data entry code and add some input validation to prevent that. One way to do this is to handle the `KeyPress` event of the `TextBox` control that's receiving the user's input - and "swallow" any invalid keys:

```
Private Sub txtInput_KeyPress(ByVal keyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If Not IsValidKeyAscii(keyAscii, txtInput.Value) Then keyAscii = 0
End Sub

Private Function IsValidKeyAscii(ByVal keyAscii As Integer, ByVal value As String) As Boolean
'returns true if specified keyAscii is a number, or if it's a dot and value doesn't already contain one
    IsValidKeyAscii = (keyAscii = vbKeyDot And InStr(1, value, Chr$(vbKeyDot)) = 0) Or (keyAscii >= vbKey0 And keyAscii <= vbKey9)
End Function
```

If the number came from an `InputBox`, you won't be able to prevent the user from entering whatever they want, but you can still validate the input and prevent bad input from being propagated further into your code.

```
Private Function PromptForNumber() As Double
    Dim isValid As Boolean
    Dim userInput As String
    Do
        userInput = InputBox("Enter a decimal number:")
        isValid = IsNumeric(userInput) And InStr(userInput, ",") = 0
        If Not isValid Then MsgBox "Value '" & userInput & "' is not numeric. Please make sure to use [en-US] decimal separator."
    While Not isValid
    PromptForNumber = CDbl(userInput)
End Function
```

There's simply no excuse for messing with the user's Control Panel settings.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation and again for the insight, Now I will have to seriously think a huge change for my code then. My excuse: I treat numbers as string because I write them to a text file. Basically I make an operation x = 3*0.1, now x is 0.3 and I have to write in the text file 0.3 not 0,3 ...

Comment: When you read the file back, convert numeric values to numeric types as soon as possible; a file is just another form of input, and all inputs require validation.

Comment: I am not the one to read the file, and the file has very strong formatting requirement coming from clients.

Comment: Well then, it's pretty simple: the only code that needs to be concerned with the file's format is the code that's writing to it! Everything else works with numbers - the file-writing code's job is to format these numbers per the file format's specifications.

Comment: Indeed you are right it is simple like this, the problem is just that this code writes quite a lot, now I have to go through a few ~300 `Replace(Number, ",", ".") ` I was hopping for a proper turn around. For my own usage it was ok to only change the settings.

Comment: Rubberduck looks Interesting, I will have a deeper look later

Comment: @Jonathan awesome! feel free to report issues (a number of 2.0.13 issues are already fixed and pending release though) and make feature requests on our GitHub repository - and star us if you like! =)

Answer (score 1):

If the [`End`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491908/whats-the-deference-between-end-and-exit-sub-in-vba) command is encountered anywhere in the code then this will foil your plan.

Take a look at the example below. If `A` calls `B` then no problem, errors are handled and when control returns to `A` the handler will still execute your locale reset. But uncomment the call to `C` and run the code again. Execution simply stops and control never returns to `A` so the reset is not performed.

So your scenario is that you send the workbook to your colleague and then they to add on some more logic which uses the `End` command for whatever reason.

```
Option Explicit

Sub A()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim foo As Long

    'call B
    B
    ' call C - uncomment to see impact
    'C

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error occurred in A"
    Debug.Print "Fixing locale stuff..."

End Sub

Sub B()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim foo As Long

    'cause an error
    foo = "bar"

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error occurred in B"
    Debug.Print Err.Description

End Sub

Sub C()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim foo As Long

    'cause an error
    foo = "bar"

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error occurred in C"
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    End

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear example! I was also expecting to overlook some issues, in the code I am using, there is fortunately no `End` statements. From looking at the reactions I think I also need to review my code entirely.