# Best practice: If tree or 'Early Out'

Tags: excel, vba

What's best practice with the following piece of code?

```
If Condition = False Then End
' Rest of my code.
```

OR

```
If Condition = True Then
    'Rest of my code.
Else
    End
End if
```

If Condition is not met in my code, I don't want to needlessly run all of my code. Is it better practice to use an If statement above my code to prevent it from running if Condition is not met, or is it better to use a more fleshed out If statement to handle this?

The latter piece of code doesn't technically require 'End', it just circumvents the execution of my code.

Comment: That depends and is opinionated.

Comment: I understand that there is no hard and fast rule, but is there no best practice regarding the issue? For instance I've read that Early Out code is good in functions, does the same apply to your main module?

Comment: It really is subjective, your example is too trivial to make a case either way.  *Lots* of levels of nesting can be considered an [Arrow Anti-Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern)

Comment: I would say that using `End` on its own is generally not good practice unless you fully understand all the consequences.

Comment: @Rory I guess the OPs intention was not `End` but using `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function` instead. @Nicolas have a look at [What's the deference between “end” and “exit sub” in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491908/whats-the-deference-between-end-and-exit-sub-in-vba) to understand the difference.

Comment: Depends. If performance is very important, make sure the result that happens most frequently is in the True part of the If statement. Also, "If Condition = True Then" is inefficient, "If Condition Then" is better.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this depends on the type of the variable `Condition`. This might look the same at first but only if we assume that `Condition` is of type `Boolean` which is not defined here.

1. If the type is `Boolean`:
   Then it is up to you which one you choose. Both are safe and I would say this is opinion based which one you prefer.
2. If the type is **not** `Boolean`:
   For `Condition` being e.g. of type `Long` or `Integer` and having a value that is not `0` (which means `false`) and not `-1` (which means `true`) for example for `Condition = 1` they behave differently. The …

   - first solution will run the rest of the code
   - but the second solution will end the code.

Answer (score 0):

See it that way : wich condition is the most likely to happen often (true or false). And than you use this condition in your code. So when your sub\function runs it will have to act on less code.

Or said an other way: having a if condition then A else B,
Be sure to place the A code first if it is happening more often than B, so your code will be faster.